# Error downloading posts from Firebase's Database (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, xcode8

I have a social app that have posts like Facebook but when i try to download the posts it returns nil.

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("following").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
    if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
        for each in snapDict{


            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").child(String(each.key)).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

                if (snapshot.value != nil)
                {
                    self.Posts.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)


                }

            }){(error) in

                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }

    }

    self.homeTableView.reloadData()

    self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()
})
```

after some debugging i reduce the problem to this line of code that return then nil value

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").child(String(each.key)).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
```

the other part of my code does return the list of people you follow and loops thought it.

this is the structure of my database.

```
{
  "Posts" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "-KbHUnL-RveUQa3MPSWp" : {
        "latitud" : "21.111401000574",
        "longitud" : "-89.6112191677094",
        "text" : "Fiesta en la Anahuac!!! ",
        "timestamp" : "1485295269.30773",
        "ubicacionN" : "Universidad Anáhuac Mayab"
      },
      "-KbI1azr6uFel-5uTZOD" : {
        "latitud" : "Optional(21.018988764483463)",
        "longitud" : "Optional(-89.614319546492695)",
        "text" : "Hola chicos",
        "timestamp" : "1485304393.77929",
        "ubicacionN" : "Calle 53-A 341"
      },
      "-KbNQWxjQhc0Ce_ZQbq9" : {
        "latitud" : "Optional(21.019219877217914)",
        "longitud" : "Optional(-89.614173537203683)",
        "text" : "Hola",
        "timestamp" : "1485394812.83039",
        "ubicacionN" : "Calle 53 341"
      }
    },
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "-KbQOWfUnzY1JiS61J6-" : {
        "latitud" : "Optional(21.111502615883129)",
        "longitud" : "Optional(-89.611767497121221)",
        "text" : "Hola chicos!",
        "timestamp" : "1485444619.10931",
        "ubicacionN" : "Carretera Mérida-Progreso 96"
      }
    }
  },
  "follower" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : true
    },
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : true
    }
  },
  "following" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : true
    },
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : true
    }
  },
  "handles" : {
    "jcadmin" : "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2",
    "jcbest" : "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2"
  },
  "user_profiles" : {
    "dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2" : {
      "about" : "Hola Mundo",
      "handle" : "jcbest",
      "name" : "Juan Carlos Estevez Rodriguez",
      "profile_pic" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jalo-267da.appspot.com/o/user_profiles%2FOptional(%22dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2%22)%2Fprofile_pic?alt=media&token=bfc3c516-7849-472c-b7cd-9668965a5dbe"
    },
    "mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2" : {
      "about" : "Hola chicos",
      "handle" : "jcadmin",
      "name" : "Juan Carlos",
      "profile_pic" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/jalo-267da.appspot.com/o/user_profiles%2FOptional(%22mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2%22)%2Fprofile_pic?alt=media&token=b741b6c1-0bc5-446d-a1e5-159b21e770d2"
    }
  }
}
```

this is my entire code.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u7saz4mdbehw1gd/AACv2rZH7M8jS_lU-plSqwc5a?dl=0

Comment: Does `String(each.key)` return exactly what you're looking for?
What is returned if you remove the queryOrderedBy clause?

Comment: @Russell yes indeed, `String(each.key)` returns the other users UID. I just tried removing queryOrderBy nothing happens either.

Comment: Are you using Disk Persistence?

Comment: I don't think so @AlissonEnz I don't actually know what it is. :(

Comment: but if you can see the data in the Firebase console, you should be able to retrieve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem after a lot of debuging and as it tourns out the problem was that in this part

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Posts").child(String(each.key)).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in

                if (snapshot.value != nil)
                {
                    self.Posts.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)


                }

            }){(error) in

                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
```

the Query was actually downloading all the posts but they were kept in a non static varaible (noob error) so the only thing I had to do was reload the data just after it got every post, that is to say that it needed to be like this:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Jalas").child(each.key).queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

                        print(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)

                        self.Jalas.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)
                        self.homeTableView.reloadData()
                    })
```

so the complete code looks something like this:

```
        self.homeTableView.delegate = self
        self.homeTableView.dataSource = self

        self.loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

        print("LoggedInUser: " + (self.loggedInUser?.uid)!)


        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("following").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: true).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in

            //if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

            let sanpDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]
            if (sanpDict != nil)
            {
                for each in sanpDict!{

                    print("each.key es: " + String(each.key))

                    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Jalas").child(each.key).queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

                        print(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)

                        self.Jalas.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)
                        self.homeTableView.reloadData()
                    })

                }
        }


            self.aivLoading.stopAnimating()
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a valid data set, then you're looking for the wrong thing in your query, but it could be that I just don't understand your data!

I'm assuming that the `currentUser`  is `dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2`, and that the first query to get those following should return `mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2`

You don't have any reference to `mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2` in the posts, so you're never going to get anything returned in the second query ...

Comment: your right, sorry this the un updated version of my data base. let me updated it. @Russell

Comment: done @Russell as you can see what i do is getting the query of the people you who are under following and under your UID, but only those who's value is equal to true (it can be false if the user unfollows you) the `each.key` does return `mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2` i check it with a `print(each.key)`

Comment: and @Russell indeed, in this case lets asume `currentUser` is `dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2`.

Comment: how odd.  Works just fine for me.  

Are you confident that the data for posts has been stored in Firebase exactly as you have shown it here?  Could you include a screenshot of the Firebase console?

Comment: damn, yes ahahah @Russell I downloaded directly from firebase as JSON and copy and paste it. :( any idea?

Comment: this is my original code (in my code I use the word "Jalas" insted of "Posts"). https://www.dropbox.com/sh/u7saz4mdbehw1gd/AACv2rZH7M8jS_lU-plSqwc5a?dl=0

Comment: Can you confirm that `FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid` is returning the value that you're expecting?  What happens if you hard-code that (as I did) to `dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2 `

Comment: just put in my code `print("LoggedInUser: " + (self.loggedInUser?.uid)!)` it does return `dEXaVLDOSPfJa3zTyUNqAEtVuMR2` :(

Comment: curious.
humour me - take a screenshot of the Firebase console, and stick it in the Dropbox folder.  It doesn't make sense that I can copy your code, recreate your data - and it works for me.

There must be SOMETHING different!

Comment: Ok just uploaded the pics hahaha, also I realized of this Warning: `2017-01-30 14:45:19.295 Jalo[3254] <Warning> [Firebase/Database][I-RDB03428] Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": ".value" at /following/mt0fzirhMhazIcy90MRWuRpTfmE2 to your security rules for better performance
` does it means something?? @Russell

Comment: it's worth adding the index for performance - but it won't make any difference in this case.

Comment: well - your firebase console looks identical to mine, so nothing different there.

I think I have run out of ideas - but I think it would be worth seeing if you can query the posts directly - set up a dummy method to simply return all posts, then all posts for a hard-coded user id